# How to control hooks between 2 components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, popup

I wanted to know if I can send from one component to another property to define a state.
Like a popup, I have a "Start now" button and I want to popup the reg form and make the "start now" button disappear and to close the popup in when I click on an logo img in the form.
ex:

first component

```
function RegisterPage (props){
    return(
      <form className="All-Register">
        <div className="Register-Header">
          <img src={Logo} name="Logo" onClick={() => props.setIsOpen(!props.isOpen)}/>
        </div>
        <div className="Register-Form">
          <input type="text" placeholder="nick_name" />
          <input type="text" placeholder="email" />
          <input type="password" placeholder="pass" />
          <input type="submit" value="register" />
        </div>
        <div className="Forgot">
          <span>forgot pass</span>
        </div>
      </form>
    )
}
export default RegisterPage;
```

second component

```
function RegisterButton(){
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  return(
    <div>
      {isOpen ? <RegisterPage isOpen = {isOpen} /> :
      <div className="HomeWrapper">
        <div className="para">
          <p>Build the strongest army</p>
          <p>and join the fight-club</p>
        </div>
        <div className="div-btn">
          <button className="Reg-Btn" onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>start now</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    }
    </div>
  );
}

export default RegisterButton;
```

ty for your help :)

Comment: [Lift your state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: Hes actually already got it in the right place. Confusing but `RegisterButton` has the state and `RegisterPage` lives inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new `onLogoClick` prop to `RegisterPage` which is attached the the `onClick` of the `<img/>`. Then bind this in the `RegisterButton` parent to a function which set the state to false.

```
function RegisterPage (props){
    return(
      <form className="All-Register">
        <div className="Register-Header">
          <img src={Logo} name="Logo" onClick={props.onLogoClick}/>
        </div>
        <div className="Register-Form">
          <input type="text" placeholder="nick_name" />
          <input type="text" placeholder="email" />
          <input type="password" placeholder="pass" />
          <input type="submit" value="register" />
        </div>
        <div className="Forgot">
          <span>forgot pass</span>
        </div>
      </form>
    )
}
export default RegisterPage;
```

```
function RegisterButton(){
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  return(
    <div>
      {isOpen ? <RegisterPage isOpen={isOpen} onLogoClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}/> :
      <div className="HomeWrapper">
        <div className="para">
          <p>Build the strongest army</p>
          <p>and join the fight-club</p>
        </div>
        <div className="div-btn">
          <button className="Reg-Btn" onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>start now</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    }
    </div>
  );
}

export default RegisterButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways -

1. Pass another prop setIsOpen then you can able to use the onClick function you define.
2. This way I prefer you to use. Create a function then use toggle there. Then pass that function to your register component as prop then call it from onClick on image.
   I hope you get my points.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to

```
   {!isOpen ? (
          <button className="Reg-Btn" onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>
            start now
          </button>
        ) : null}
```